# How do I add/adjust words in/to the keyboard dictionary on iOS?

Tags: ios, dictionary

I want to add some common building names for my college campus to my keyboard dictionary, but in the General tab in Settings, I only see an option to reset the dictionary.

I tried typing the words, expecting to see a red squiggly underneath them and then an option to add the words to the dictionary, but only a suggested edit was there.

It added one of the buildings =, but only because it tried to auto-correct to something else but I corrected it and it added itself to the dict.

But other names that have no auto-correct don't get added.

Also, I want to adjust a word that was added by making it auto-correct to being capitalized. And I want to remove some of the autocorrects like correcting "te" to "the" instead of the preprogrammed "TE", etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to Setttings > General > Keyboard.
2. Tap Edit in the top right corner.
3. Tap Add New Shortcut. Type the word you wanted to add to the dictionary in the Phrase field. You can also optionally add a shortcut.
4. Add a shortcut with the Phrase TE and the shortcut te. This will auto-capitalise te to TE. It will also prevent it from auto-correcting to the.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to do the opposite of what you mentioned for TE. I want it to correct to the instead of TE. But the method is the same! Thanks! I didn't think this was the user dictionary, I thought it was a shortcut or something, but I guess they do the same things.

Comment: You’re welcome. Next time, just explore things yourself a bit. If you still can’t solve a problem, Ask Different!